# Handling Missing values in data

Tags: data-cleaning

I have a Machine Learning task wherein I have to predict a target variable using an input. However, my dataset has a considerable percentage of missing values. What is the best approach to handle it?

On running the following script, I calculate the percentage of missing values in each input feature.

```
# Calculate the percentage of null val# Calculate the percentage of null values column-wise
null_percentage = (df.isnull().sum() / len(df)) * 100
sorted_null_percentage = null_percentage.sort_values(ascending=False)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(sorted_null_percentage.values)
pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

And the percentages are as follows:-

> [9.99116433e+01 9.99116433e+01 9.93788378e+01 9.93788378e+01
> 9.93788378e+01 9.93788378e+01 9.14593223e+01 8.79589399e+01
> 7.71387651e+01 7.66249457e+01 7.07246898e+01 7.07246898e+01
> 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01
> 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01
> 6.74590502e+01 6.74590502e+01 6.60857853e+01 6.56559071e+01
> 6.37467704e+01 6.20709048e+01 6.20709048e+01 5.54769354e+01
> 5.37712415e+01 5.26348044e+01 5.26348044e+01 5.24136348e+01
> 4.78674941e+01 4.78674941e+01 4.78674941e+01 4.78674941e+01
> 4.78674941e+01 3.52821894e+01 3.37223174e+01 3.15739325e+01
> 2.07080013e+01 2.07080013e+01 2.07080013e+01 2.07080013e+01
> 2.07080013e+01 2.07080013e+01 2.07080013e+01 1.80212916e+01
> 1.67438159e+01 1.67438159e+01 1.55705758e+01 1.24338654e+01
> 1.24338654e+01 7.70811689e+00 7.70811689e+00 5.47079480e+00
> 5.46558628e+00 4.99510302e+00 4.99510302e+00 4.81371267e+00
> 3.28626920e+00 6.60295546e-01 2.68831228e-01 3.36141242e-02
> 1.38593872e-02 1.38593872e-02 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
> 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]

Comment: Do you know the mechanism through which the data is arising? Why is it missing? If you can come up with this you can incorporate mechanism of data going missing into your modelling process